# Отправка данных в базу данных по клике на ссылку

Tags: php, html, mysql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Я сейчас работаю с базовой данных. У меня в бд есть таблица, в ней есть записи.
В файле admin.php я эти записи из таблицы вывожу на экран. И напротив каждой записи покав ссылку "Санкционировать".

```
<a href = "approvescore.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '&amp;data=' . $row['data'] . '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . '&amp;score=' . $row['score'] . '&amp;screenshot=' . $row['screenshot'] . '">Санкціонувати!</a>
```

В ссылке передаются все необходимые данные. А в файле approvescore.php выполняется вся логика. Суть была в том что кликая по ссылке "Санкционировать" в таблицу в бд в колонке "approved" записывалось значение "1". Это означает, что запись санкционировано есть проверено. И все записи в которых в колонке "approved" имеет значение "1", отображаются на главной сторицни.

С файлом admin.php ниякийх проблем нет все записи без проблем вилодяться на экран.

Я уже делал нечто подобное, но с формами. Там в HTML был тег input.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Добавити!">
```

В PHP я делал так:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $score = $_POST['score'];
```

//всередині підключався до бази даних, писав запит до бд і все було добре. 
}

Но в случае с ссылками "Санкционировать" так не получилось, поэтому еще не форма а просто ссылка.

Я решил сделать по другому. Я читаю сейчас книгу и там используют в таких случаях и $ _GET метод и $ _POST.

$ _GET для того чтобы проверить на ссылку кликнули. Это первое условие if.
А внутри еще один if или else if, там уже проверяют $ _POST. И этим методом в бд записываются нужные данные. То внутри этого if с $ _POST идет подключение к базе данных и запрос записывающий нужную информацию.

У меня с $ _POST почему-то ничего не работает. А с $ _GET как я понимаю к бд информацию немож записать.
Максимум что у меня получилось это то, что я проверяю на условие или ссылка нажата. Посредством $ _GET. Код внутри этой условия выполняется но не совсем, к бдинформация НЕ записуетья, но выводится сообщение о том, что все успешно прошло, и информация о запросе тоже вся отображается в сообщении.

Как мне это решить. Нужно использовать $ _GET и $ _POST? Так я я писал? Или это можно подругому реализовать?

Ссилка:

```
<a href = "approvescore.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '&amp;data=' . $row['data'] . '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . '&amp;score=' . $row['score'] . '&amp;screenshot=' . $row['screenshot'] . '">Санкціонувати!</a>
```

approvescore.php:

```
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['score']) && isset($_GET['data']) && isset($_GET['screenshot'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $score = $_GET['score'];
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    $screenshot = $_GET['screenshot'];

        $connect = mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'gwdb');

        mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE `guitarwars` SET `approved` = '1' WHERE `id` = '$id'");

        echo 'Рейтинг ' . $score . ' для пользователя ' . $name . ' успешно санкционировано! ';

        mysqli_close($connect);


    } else {'Вибачте, виникла проблема з санкціонуванням рейтингу!';}
```

echo 'Назад к странице администратора!';

Answer (score 1):

У Вас рабочий код. Только зачем Вы передаете data и screenshot? Они нигде в коде не используются. Также, обратите внимание, что максимальная длина адресной строки - 255 символов, а GET параметры именно в ней передаются.
Дальше Вы получаете id записи и просто выполняете запрос на обновление. Все верно. Если скрипт не работает, то проблема в чем-то другом. Возможно, в базе название атрибутов другое. Попробуйте вывести SQL ошибку https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Но повторюсь, код приведенный выше рабочий. И здесь можно обойтись без POST запроса. Но не забывайте делать защиту, чтобы любой не смог просто ввести что-то в адресную строку и накрутить себе очков)